# Loop through multiple DataTables (share same column)

Tags: c#, datatable

I have e.g. 4 DataTables:

```
private void Test()
{
    DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
    table1.Columns.Add("MyId");
    table1.Columns.Add("Column1");
    table1.Columns.Add("Column2");

    DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
    table2.Columns.Add("Column3");
    table2.Columns.Add("MyId");
    table2.Columns.Add("Column4");

    DataTable table3 = new DataTable();
    table3.Columns.Add("Column5");
    table3.Columns.Add("MyId");
    table3.Columns.Add("Column6");

    DataTable table4 = new DataTable();
    table4.Columns.Add("Column7");
    table4.Columns.Add("Column8");
    table4.Columns.Add("MyId");

    DataSet set = new DataSet();
    set.Tables.Add(table1);
    set.Tables.Add(table2);
    set.Tables.Add(table3);
    set.Tables.Add(table4);

    set.Relations.Add("MYKEY", table1.Columns["MyId"], table2.Columns["MyId"]);
    set.Relations.Add("MYKEY", table1.Columns["MyId"], table3.Columns["MyId"]);
    set.Relations.Add("MYKEY", table1.Columns["MyId"], table4.Columns["MyId"]);

    foreach (DataTable dt in set.Tables)
    {
        foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows[0].GetChildRows("MYKEY"))
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(item["MyId"]);
            string column1 = item["Column1"].ToString();
            string column8 = item["Column8"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Is is possible to implement a relation where all DataTables are connected based on the 'MyId' column? I would like to loop through all rows with just one loop.

I already read the ['Adding DataRelations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ay82azad(v=vs.110).aspx)' on the MSDN site, but I can't define multiple relations with the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the short answer to your question is "*No, there isn't a way to loop through all rows in all related tables with just one loop utilizing the `DataRelation` class or a set thereof*".

The DataRelation class is designed [to my best understanding] to provide constraints in code that are typically enforced at database level, such as Primary Key -> Foreign Key relationships. However, it is not really designed to easily traverse the data - that is, knowledge of underlying data structure (tables/columns) is necessary for data access.

There are ways to collect the data via a single loop, but I am not sure how meaningful such data collection would be. Here's an example using a `Dictionary<int, List<Tuple<string, object>>>`, where key is a primary key in your table, and data is grouped into *column name/value* pairs:

```
        var data = new Dictionary<int, List<Tuple<string, object>>>();

        foreach (DataRow row in table1.Rows)
        {
            /* Pull data from "main" table */

            int id = Convert.ToInt32(row["MyId"]);
            var rowData = new List<Tuple<string, object>>();

            foreach (DataColumn column in table1.Columns)
            {
                string columnName = column.ColumnName;
                var columnData = new Tuple<string, object>(columnName, row[columnName]);

                rowData.Add(columnData);
            }

            //Collect data from each related table
            foreach (DataRelation relation in set.Relations)
            {
                foreach (DataRow relatedRow in row.GetChildRows(relation))
                {
                    foreach (DataColumn column in relation.ChildTable.Columns)
                    {
                        if (relation.ChildColumns.Contains(column))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        string columnName = column.ColumnName;
                        var columnData = new Tuple<string, object>(columnName, relatedRow[columnName]);

                        rowData.Add(columnData);
                    }
                }
            }

            //Add to data dictionary
            data.Add(id, rowData);
        }
```

The advantage of the above code is no dependency on table structure at all (except the obvious need to identify main table and primary key); but you'd still need to write quite a bit of code to meaningfully parse the resulting data structure.

I think a LINQ query would be much more clear and expressive in this case. I know this is not what you asked for, but just in case you're interested, here's a LINQ solution, which provides a "SQL view" equivalent of the data, represented as an enumerable of [in my mind] meaningful objects:

```
var fullDataView = from t1data in table1.AsEnumerable()
                           join t2data in table2.AsEnumerable()
                           on t1data["MyId"] equals t2data["MyId"]
                           join t3data in table3.AsEnumerable()
                           on t1data["MyId"] equals t3data["MyId"]
                           join t4data in table4.AsEnumerable()
                           on t1data["MyId"] equals t4data["MyId"]
                           select new
                           {
                               MyId = t1data["MyId"],
                               Column1 = t1data["Column1"],
                               Column2 = t1data["Column2"],
                               Column3 = t2data["Column3"],
                               Column4 = t2data["Column4"],
                               Column5 = t3data["Column5"],
                               Column6 = t3data["Column6"],
                               Column7 = t4data["Column7"],
                               Column8 = t4data["Column8"]
                           };
```